# How to output the cropped resolution

Tags: davinci-resolve

### Scenario

I recorded a video that looks like this:
[image: Nintendo Switch virtual console]

(which is 1920x1080) But I want to crop the video to only have the actual game rectangle. In MS Paint I measured that the game rectangle is 1435x957 (although odd numbers aren't supported for mp4). So far, the cropping I've tried has resulted in black bars (which is what I'm trying to remove in the first place).

### Settings

For my Project Settings > Master settings > Timeline format > Timeline resolution I have set to 1434x956 and have Project Settings > Image Scaling > Output scaling set to match timeline settings and for Mismatched resolutions files I've tried stretch and both scales (for the same result). My actual timeline's settings use the project settings. In the deliver tab the resolution is likewise 1434x956.

### Steps

On the edit tab I used the frame's drop down for cropping a box which generates video cropping values of about 176.599, 180.145, 21.862, 66.592 (which aren't in pixels and thus arbitrary). The video transform section remains default (zoom 1, positions 0).

The resulting video is indeed 1434x956 (as per the file properties in windows) but it also has black bars (which can be detected by resizing the video player's window to show that the gameplay doesn't reach the edges like my normal videos do). So, despite the zoom of 1 it seems like the source was zoomed out. The crop is certainly doing something since it replaces the profile icon and controls with black bars (so yes: it is being applied to the video track of the timeline).

Yes, I tried deleting the source/timeline from the cut tab and re-adding them. Doing so didn't say anything about "source will be resized".

### Work around

Instead of cropping if I use video transform of zoom 1.330 and position 5, -33 I can get it to render into 1434x956. But it seems like there should be a better way of doing this.

### Question

How can I prevent my source from being zoomed out? Is there any way to crop and have the output be whatever size the resulting rectangle is (rather than manually setting 1434x956)? If not (to both), is there a way to get the crop result to auto zoom/position to fit the output size?

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Crop the video and output just that. But no, the two are separate steps, and it is not clear how to just encode the cropped rectangle instead of the entire FHD video. - Note that in the Inspector, you can specify clean and straight pixel values for cropping.